# How can I repair Windows 10 UEFI Normal Boot?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, uefi

I  have Windows 10 (home premium) installed on a SSD in a desktop.  It was booting just fine until a couple of months ago.

I CAN boot Windows in SAFE MODE.

I have a Windows 10 DVD that I burned myself after I upgraded from Windows 7.

My personal files are on another drive, so no worries about loosing them.

I have the passwords for the two accounts I created when I originally installed Windows 7, which have not changed since.  One is administrative the other a regular one.

I also have Linux installed and GRUB (boot loader) but I don't think they are involved in this problem.  Linux (Xubuntu 16.04 LTS) is installed on a HDD and is booting fine, except that sometimes I have two NTFS partitions on the same HDD, to be shared between systems, that periodically need fixing with a one liner but that's it.  I think that this is caused by some of my failed attempts to start Windows.  Whatever causes it I'll deal with it later.

The two (2) NTFS partitions in question are also on the HDD with Linux.

The EFI System Partition (fat32 or vfat) used to boot Windows is the first partition on my SSD, first drive, no letter in Windows.  Windows is on C:.

I am desperately trying to avoid re-installing Windows because I have many installed drivers/programs & settings tweaks, and because I worry I will mess up my Linux installation.  I know that Windows behaves badly with other OSes.

I believe that the problem so far with Windows is independent of GRUB and Linux because I select Windows directly from the UEFI screen, not going through GRUB, and I get a few reboots followed by:

> Recovery
>
> Your PC couldn't start properly. After multiple tries...
>
> Error code: 0xC0000001
>
> You'll need to user recovery tools

It all started with my attempts to fix the problem with:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

which produced:

> cannot find the file specified.

I tried booting with my Windows-10 DVD which works but none of the suggestions I found on the Web were fruitful for me, including Startup Repair:

> Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC.
>
> Press "Advance options" to try...
>
> Log file: C:\WINDOWS\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrial.txt

I copied that file to read it later in Linux but the text editors I used (leafpad, mousepad) were unable to open it.  I tried all of the encodings shown in Mousepad, two dozens of them, but none worked.

I then tried a whole bunch of stuff, including:

```
> bootsect /nt60 sys
> bootrec /rebuildBCD
> DISKPART list vol, sel vol ('3' for me), assign letter= ('S' for me)
> bcdboot C:\WINDOWS /s S: /f UEFI
```

and

```
C:\Windows\System32>msconfig
```

produced:

> You do not have sufficient privileges ...

and

```
X:\Sources>sfc /scannow
```

produced:

> Beginning system scan...
>
> Beginning verification phase...
>
> Verification 100% complete.
>
> Windows Resource Protection could not perform the
>   requested operation.

At this point I need to ask for help because I'm starting to get lost in my notes and it's time consuming to have to boot into Linux to do what I'm doing now, then write everything down on paper, then reboot into Windows, then try, write down the results, reboot into Linux and start that sequence again.  I only have one computer.  As far as my research and my attempts at solving this, I am past the point of diminishing returns now.

EDIT (1)

UEFI screen options:

> CSM Support:                             Always
>
> - Boot Mode Selection:                UEFI Only
> - PXE Boot Option Control:            Disabled
> - Storage Boot Option Control:        UEFI First
> - Display Boot Option Control:        UEFI Only
>
> Other PCI Device ROM Priority:             UEFI OpRom

I have played (worked painstakingly) on booting problems in the past with this machine, starting with Xubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 and I need to be very careful with these settings.  I am not absolutely certain that it is still true but selecting "Never" for "CSM Support" (legacy mode) prevented booting when I had made sure that everything was strictly GPT and UEFI.  It didn't seem logical to me but that's what happened.  Ever since my initial installation of both OSes, back when I didn't know much about UEFI and ended up making mistakes even if I had decided from the start to be exclusively UEFI (to make thing simpler... ha ha ha).  So that's why you see here "Always" for CSM Support and "UEFI Only" for Boot Mode Selection, this second one being the important one I think.

EDIT (2)

As a side note I just saw a post on another forum by chance where there is an option in Windows 10 -> Troubleshoot -> Advanced options called "UEFI Firmware Settings" which IS NOT present here on my system.  I don't know if it matters but I thought I should post this just in case.  There is something I don't know.  I know for a fact that my installation of Windows and Linux are UEFI and that both drives (1 ssd, 1 hdd) are GPT formatted, so I don't know why I'm not getting that option.

EDIT (3)

Hibernation is NOT enabled in Windows.  (I verified using Safe Mode, the only way I can get into Windows.)

EDIT (4)

I tried booting Windows with "clean boot", i.e. disabled all non-Microsoft services in System Configuration (msconfig) and all items in Task Manager Startup tab.  The result was the same.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootsect /nt60 `. You are probably using UEFI on  GPT, not MBR with a boot record. Any command to mess with a not-existing (and not needed) MBR or bootsector will not solve your problem.

Comment: @ Hennes: Yes gpt formatted, UEFI only for both my SSD and my HDD.  Thanks for that.

Comment: my motherboard:  Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD3H rev-1

Comment: QUESTION:  I don't want to cross post but maybe I could ask in a strictly "windows" forum about my "EDIT (4)"?  (What to do when doing a clean boot doesn't allow to boot normally?)  I'm thinking that perhaps my original question here should have been asked in a forum geared for regular users instead of "Super" users ;-)  I'm not sure.

Comment: `"Never" for "CSM Support" (legacy mode) prevented booting when I had made sure that everything was strictly GPT and UEFI. It didn't seem logical to me but that's what happened. ` Uhm. that confuses me. Do you have grub on MBR/in_partition and windows on ESP/bootx64.efi?

Comment: @Hennes: From the reading I have done it seems that we cannot talk about MBR in my system.  Like I wrote in my answer to your first comment/question BOTH my drives are GPT formatted and boot in UEFI mode.  Windows is on the first and Xubuntu on the second one.  GRUB is on the second drive in its ESP (sdb1 mounted on /boot/grub in Xubuntu) along with /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/.  There is also an ESP on my first drive which contains the Windows 10 boot files (sda1).  Windows itself is on sda2.  I wish I could make a diagram but I can't in this "comments" section.

Comment: Oh, yes, one more thing: I have installed rEFInd and it lives on sda1 (ESP on Windows' drive).  I didn't mention it earlier because I didn't think it was relevant here.  When I try to boot into Windows I'm not using it, I go directly to my UEFI firmware screens and select it there as the first device in the boot order.  I'm trying to not mention stuff that is not necessary/useful to keep things as simple as possible.  Besides, rEFInd is working fine so there's no need to involve it in my present predicament.

Comment: As I understand it there is no need for more than one single ESP. One drive with ESP, multiple OS loaders on that single ESP should 'just work'.  But since you can boot windows in safe mode this is not a boot-loader issue.  Instead I wonder what goes wrong and why. This includes you not being able to read SrtTrial.txt. From what I read on the web this is a regular text file. Not being able to read that makes me wonder if either the filesystem, the folder or the file is corrupted.

Comment: @Hennes: 1) I keep one ESP on each drive in case one of the two drives fails.  It's not supposed to hurt, not against the UEFI specs afaik.  2) I was able to open and read SrtTrial.txt from inside Windows, RESULTS: two tests done: a) check for updates -> OK  b) System disk test -> OK  c) Root cause found: "A hard disk could not be found.  If a hard disk is installed, it is not responding."  Nothing seems wrong with sda (SSD); I can mount either sda1 (ESP) or sda2 (Windows system) when I look at them in Linux, and I can boot Windows in safe mode.

Answer (score 4):

1. Boot your Windows 10 DVD using UEFI boot (or disable CSM, so you cannot boot using boot records)
2. Map EFI System on SSD to Z: using diskpart
3. **bcdboot c:\windows /s Z: /f UEFI**

assuming c: maps to Windows partition on SSD.

Forget about unreliable bootrec - the main problem seems to be inability to find EFI System.

Other problem you have - disable fastboot so Windows 10 does a full restart (and full shutdown)

And ... forget about MBR on UEFI (one of the main reasons for implementing EFI is to get rid of MBR and its limitations and problems)

Comment: Done for 1, 2, 3: same result as before, "Boot files successfully created", I then rebooted in my Windows installation on SSD, and the result is: "Recovery", "Your PC couldn't start properly", "After multiple tries...needs to be repaired", "Error code: 0xc0000001" ...

Comment: The only option in my UEFI screen that may be related to "fastboot" is called "Intel Rapid Start Technology" and it has always been disabled and still is.  I just verified again.

Comment: I added a layout of some UEFI options followed by comments.  If we determine that I MUST select "Never" for "CSM Support" (i.e. that "UEFI Only" for "Boot Mode Selection" is not enough) I will do it.  Unless you or someone else tells me otherwise and is fairly certain, I'd rather keep it as is.

Comment: I mean it is easier not to use CSM boot (=MBR boot) when you have UEFI/GPT disk. Then you can boot external media only UEFI way. CSM is only useful for older versions of Windows - Windows 7 for example needs CSM when booting to recovery.

Comment: "fastboot" is part of Windows 8/10 power settings - something like hibernation when you shut down (for faster start-up later). BUT when you dual-boot hibernation means remembering state of open files and when you use another OS in the meantime disk gets corrupted for the hibernated OS.

Comment: The problem with error 0xc0000001 is that Windows has raised a flag already that it did not boot properly one time and now insists doing its checks and repairs (if needed). Let it run, fix problems and clear this 0xc0000001 flag. The main thing when dual-booting is not to use "fastboot" which you should disable when Win10 is up and running. And never hibernate Windows when you intend to use another OS.

Comment: I can't chat because not enough reputation points.  I'll go into Windows Safe Mode and see what I can do there.  I've tried to disable everything in Windows since Windows 7 and from reading I knew, way back, not to activate/enable hibernation.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hibernation is NOT enabled.  I just checked. I added that as an "Edit" in my original question.  I did not find anything mentioning "fastboot" though.

Comment: Sorry, the name is "Fast Startup" - ControlPanel - PowerOptions - Change settings that are currently unavailable - "Turn on fast startup" not selected = disabled.

Comment: Hibernation is disabled so there is no "fast startup" option.  It only shows up if hibernation is enabled.  It is not on my Windows 10.  That's normal, that's what I want.

Comment: @hockeykong did you solve your issue? I'm facing something quite similar where even after I successfully repaired boot files, my windows installation keeps crashing with error code 0xC0000001.

Comment: @Akaryatrh in my case, manually setting the boot via bcdboot actually did do the trick, but the 0xc0000001 screen would keep showing up due to a flag. Simply hitting enter to "try again" or whatever actually got the system to attempt to start again, and it started successfully.